# Arm Arch Linux 'startx' displays black screen on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, display, video, archlinux, xorg

**Context:** I recently got started with Arch Linux and the whole building your own distro thing. So I put Arch Linux Arm version on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B v1.2 from the Arch Linux Arm project. I put the ARMv7 image on the SD card, connected to a HDMI and went through the whole configuration process (installed sudo, added a sudo user, installed htop, git, neovim and the works).

**Problem:** I installed the X Display Manager, the `xorg` and `xorg-init` packages. The for a window manager I installed i3 as it supports ARM. Setup my `.xinitrc` to execute i3. But in the end when I tried running the `Xserver` with HDMI connected to my TV using `startx`, it displayed output until

`(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"`

which if we look at it is a problem in on itself coz its not using my `.xinitrc`. And then the display went black.

**Expected Behaviour:** Screen turns on and displays the default i3wm.

**Actual Behaviour:** Screen turns black and nothing works, no key-bindings or anything.

**What I have tried doing:**

- I tried chechking stuff with `lspci` but it just returns nothing.
- I also tried connecting via ssh and initializing `X11` over ssh forwarding using Xming and Putty on a Windows 10 machine. It gave this output:

```
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.7
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux archpi 6.1.11-1-rpi-ARCH #1 SMP Fri Feb 10 10:55:44 MST 2023 armv7l
Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_headphones=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=0 video=Composite-1:720x480@60i,margin_left=32,margin_right=32,margin_top=32,margin_bottom=32 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 fsck.repair=yes

Current version of pixman: 0.42.2
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Feb 12 13:52:03 2023
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Failed to connect to bus: No medium found
dbus-update-activation-environment: error: unable to connect to D-Bus: Using X11 for dbus-daemon autolaunch was disabled at compile time, set your DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS instead
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc: line 51: twm: command not found
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc: line 52: xclock: command not found
```

I am supplying the `Xorg` log file from `/var/log` as I cannot make sense of them myself.

**Xorg Log file:**

```
[ 12300.964] 
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.7
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[ 12300.964] Current Operating System: Linux archpi 6.1.11-1-rpi-ARCH #1 SMP Fri Feb 10 10:55:44 MST 2023 armv7l
[ 12300.964] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_headphones=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=0 video=Composite-1:720x480@60i,margin_left=32,margin_right=32,margin_top=32,margin_bottom=32 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 fsck.repair=yes
[ 12300.964]  
[ 12300.965] Current version of pixman: 0.42.2
[ 12300.965]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[ 12300.965] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 12300.965] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Feb 12 13:53:43 2023
[ 12300.966] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 12300.966] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[ 12300.966] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[ 12300.966] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[ 12300.966] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[ 12300.967] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[ 12300.967] (==) Automatically adding devices
[ 12300.967] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[ 12300.967] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[ 12300.967] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[ 12300.967] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[ 12300.967] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/misc" does not exist.
[ 12300.967]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 12300.967] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/TTF" does not exist.
[ 12300.967]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 12300.967] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/OTF" does not exist.
[ 12300.967]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 12300.968] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1" does not exist.
[ 12300.968]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 12300.968] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/75dpi
[ 12300.968] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[ 12300.968] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[ 12300.968] (II) Module ABI versions:
[ 12300.968]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[ 12300.968]    X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
[ 12300.968]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
[ 12300.968]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[ 12300.970] (--) using VT number 2

[ 12300.970] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[ 12300.976] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[ 12300.976] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/platform/soc/soc:gpu/drm/card0
[ 12300.978] (II) no primary bus or device found
[ 12300.978]    falling back to /sys/devices/platform/soc/soc:gpu/drm/card0
[ 12300.978] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[ 12300.979] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[ 12300.987] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 12300.988]    compiled for 1.21.1.7, module version = 1.0.0
[ 12300.988]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[ 12300.988] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[ 12300.988] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[ 12300.988] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[ 12300.988] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[ 12300.988] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[ 12300.991] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 12300.991]    compiled for 1.21.1.7, module version = 1.21.1
[ 12300.991]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 12300.991]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 12300.991] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[ 12300.991] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[ 12300.992] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 12300.992]    compiled for 1.21.1.1, module version = 0.5.0
[ 12300.992]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 12300.992]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 12300.992] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[ 12300.992] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[ 12300.992] (II) modeset(0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[ 12300.992] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[ 12300.993] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[ 12300.993] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[ 12300.993] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[ 12300.993] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 12300.993]    compiled for 1.21.1.7, module version = 0.0.2
[ 12300.994]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 12300.994] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[ 12300.995] (II) modeset(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[ 12300.995] (==) modeset(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[ 12300.995] (==) modeset(0): RGB weight 888
[ 12300.995] (==) modeset(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[ 12300.995] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[ 12300.995] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[ 12300.996] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[ 12301.026] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 12301.026]    compiled for 1.21.1.7, module version = 1.0.1
[ 12301.026]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[ 12301.210] (II) modeset(0): glamor X acceleration enabled on VC4 V3D 2.1
[ 12301.210] (II) modeset(0): glamor initialized
[ 12301.210] (==) modeset(0): VariableRefresh: disabled
[ 12301.210] (==) modeset(0): AsyncFlipSecondaries: disabled
[ 12301.212] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 has no monitor section
[ 12301.221] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output HDMI-1
[ 12301.221] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 disconnected
[ 12301.221] (WW) modeset(0): No outputs definitely connected, trying again...
[ 12301.221] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 disconnected
[ 12301.221] (WW) modeset(0): Unable to find connected outputs - setting 1024x768 initial framebuffer
[ 12301.221] (==) modeset(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[ 12301.221] (==) modeset(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[ 12301.221] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[ 12301.221] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[ 12301.221] (II) Module "fb" already built-in
[ 12301.221] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[ 12301.221] (II) Unloading fbdev
[ 12301.222] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[ 12301.222] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[ 12301.359] (==) modeset(0): Backing store enabled
[ 12301.359] (==) modeset(0): Silken mouse enabled
[ 12301.360] (II) modeset(0): Initializing kms color map for depth 24, 8 bpc.
[ 12301.361] (==) modeset(0): DPMS enabled
[ 12301.361] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[ 12301.361] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: vc4
[ 12301.361] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: vc4
[ 12301.361] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[ 12301.362] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[ 12301.363] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[ 12301.364] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[ 12301.365] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[ 12301.366] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[ 12301.366] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[ 12301.367] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[ 12301.368] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[ 12301.369] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[ 12301.370] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[ 12301.371] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[ 12301.372] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[ 12301.373] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[ 12301.374] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[ 12301.375] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[ 12301.376] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[ 12301.377] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[ 12301.378] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[ 12301.379] (II) Initializing extension Present
[ 12301.379] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[ 12301.380] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[ 12301.381] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[ 12301.382] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[ 12301.382] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[ 12301.405] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized vc4
[ 12301.405] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[ 12301.405] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[ 12301.406] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[ 12301.407] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[ 12301.407] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[ 12301.408] (II) modeset(0): Damage tracking initialized
[ 12301.860] (II) config/udev: Adding input device vc4-hdmi (/dev/input/event0)
[ 12301.860] (**) vc4-hdmi: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 12301.860] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[ 12301.860] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[ 12301.874] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 12301.874]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 1.2.1
[ 12301.874]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[ 12301.874]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.4
[ 12301.874] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'vc4-hdmi'
[ 12301.875] (**) vc4-hdmi: always reports core events
[ 12301.875] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[ 12301.885] (II) event0  - vc4-hdmi: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Pointingstick
[ 12301.886] (II) event0  - vc4-hdmi: device is a pointer
[ 12301.886] (II) event0  - vc4-hdmi: device is a keyboard
[ 12301.887] (II) event0  - vc4-hdmi: device removed
[ 12301.970] (II) libinput: vc4-hdmi: needs a virtual subdevice
[ 12301.970] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f902000.hdmi/rc/rc0/input0/event0"
[ 12301.970] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "vc4-hdmi" (type: MOUSE, id 6)
[ 12301.971] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[ 12301.972] (**) vc4-hdmi: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[ 12301.972] (**) vc4-hdmi: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[ 12301.972] (**) vc4-hdmi: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[ 12301.979] (II) event0  - vc4-hdmi: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Pointingstick
[ 12301.981] (II) event0  - vc4-hdmi: device is a pointer
[ 12301.981] (II) event0  - vc4-hdmi: device is a keyboard
[ 12302.001] (**) vc4-hdmi: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 12302.001] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'vc4-hdmi'
[ 12302.001] (**) vc4-hdmi: always reports core events
[ 12302.001] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[ 12302.001] (II) libinput: vc4-hdmi: is a virtual subdevice
[ 12302.001] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f902000.hdmi/rc/rc0/input0/event0"
[ 12302.001] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "vc4-hdmi" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[ 12305.921] (II) event0  - vc4-hdmi: device removed
[ 12305.974] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 12305.976] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 12305.986] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

**Also here's the **neofetch** output**:

`````
                   -`                    callistopi@archpi
                  .o+`                   -----------------
                 `ooo/                   OS: Arch Linux ARM armv7l
                `+oooo:                  Host: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
               `+oooooo:                 Kernel: 6.1.11-1-rpi-ARCH
               -+oooooo+:                Uptime: 3 hours, 27 mins
             `/:-:++oooo+:               Packages: 354 (pacman)
            `/++++/+++++++:              Shell: bash 5.1.16
           `/++++++++++++++:             Terminal: /dev/pts/0
          `/+++ooooooooooooo/`           CPU: BCM2835 (4) @ 1.200GHz
         ./ooosssso++osssssso+`          Memory: 53MiB / 919MiB
        .oossssso-````/ossssss+`
       -osssssso.      :ssssssso.
      :osssssss/        osssso+++.
     /ossssssss/        +ssssooo/-
   `/ossssso+/:-        -:/+osssso+-
  `+sso+:-`                 `.-/+oso:
 `++:.                           `-/+/
 .`                                 `/
`````